# RxJS performance numbers at animation speeds

Tags: javascript, performance, rxjs

Anyone have any numbers/resources on [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) performance when events happen at animation-like speeds (e.g at least 20 times a second)? I'm looking to refactor a javascript simulator (which performs simulation steps at least 20 times a second) into using events and listeners and I'd like to know if it's feasible to use RxJS as the event queue/listener solution (so I don't have to write my own).

I'm also curious about how it scales when you have up to a hundred things listening on an observable to give me an idea on how to structure the view updates (whether I should just keep a few listeners and keep a map of the set of view elements that need updating or keep it simple by just having each element register a listener).

Google searching got me this:

[Is RxJS faster than imperative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105138/is-rxjs-faster-than-imperative)

and the results are a bit concerning (10x slower than plainer code but still just an additional .005ms per event for a system with 1 listener). I'd run my own experiments as well, but any scalability info (not just performance but other things as bookkeeping and garbage collection) from someone who's used RxJS on a real project with a considerable number of listeners would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've run some preliminary experiments on RxJS 5 and here are the results:

- Setup: 10000 length event array
- Subscriber count: 1 to 20
- Output format: Rx_{*n*}x_observer : total time to process subscribe calls for *n* subscribers.

Benchmark code:

```
  var eventQueue: number[];
  var initEventQueue = function () {
    const INIT_MAX = 10000;
    eventQueue = new Array<number>(INIT_MAX);
    for (let i = 0; i < INIT_MAX; i++) {
      eventQueue[i] = i;
    }
  }

  export var testObservables = function () {
    let observable = Rx.Observable;
    initEventQueue();

    for (let OBSERVERS = 1; OBSERVERS <=20; OBSERVERS++) {
      let timerName = `Rx_${OBSERVERS}x_observer`;
      console.time(timerName);
      let eventQueueObservable = observable.from(eventQueue)
        .map(function (x: number) { return x; });

      for (let ctr = 0; ctr < OBSERVERS; ctr++) {
        eventQueueObservable
        .subscribe(function (x: number) {
          let y= x * ctr;
          return y;
        });
      }
      console.timeEnd(timerName);
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
Rx_1x_observer: 7.261962890625ms
Rx_2x_observer: 9.14794921875ms
Rx_3x_observer: 2.1669921875ms
Rx_4x_observer: 1.617919921875ms
Rx_5x_observer: 1.93310546875ms
Rx_6x_observer: 3.100830078125ms
Rx_7x_observer: 3.074951171875ms
Rx_8x_observer: 2.90673828125ms
Rx_9x_observer: 5.216796875ms
Rx_10x_observer: 4.488037109375ms
Rx_11x_observer: 5.946044921875ms
Rx_12x_observer: 4.888916015625ms
Rx_13x_observer: 5.302978515625ms
Rx_14x_observer: 5.02197265625ms
Rx_15x_observer: 7.6201171875ms
Rx_16x_observer: 7.156005859375ms
Rx_17x_observer: 6.6640625ms
Rx_18x_observer: 8.875ms
Rx_19x_observer: 9.205078125ms
Rx_20x_observer: 9.756103515625ms
```

The high numbers on the first few results are most likely a result of JIT optimizations not kicking in yet, latter results are more likely to be indicative of actual performance. If the numbers are right, the overhead is well below 0.01ms per event*subscriber, which is more than sufficient for animation-time updates (at least as long as you keep your subscriber code simple).

Unfortunately I've also found that subscribers have to be explicitly unsubscribed to avoid garbage collection issues, and this won't work with the architecture I'm aiming for. I'll probably go with a standard listener pattern using weakmaps instead.